# Guardar datos en tabla detalle - Oracle12c - JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc, oracle-12c

Por favor alguien me podría indicar cual es la forma de guardar datos en tabla maestra y tabla detalle en una ejecución utilizando base de datos oracle12c con JDBC. Los códigos de cada tabla son autoincrementados mediante la creación de SEQUENCE.

Tengo tabla PRODUCTO, VENTA y DETALLE_VENTA

Quiero guardar registros en la tabla VENTA y DETALLE_VENTA
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo muy claro como manejar los código de las tablas ya que son autogenerados y cuando guardo los datos es en ambas tablas en una sola ejecución.

La conexión ya la he realizado mediante este método:

```
protected Connection driverManagerGetConnection(String url, String user, String password) throws Exception{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es tu pregunta exactamente? Cuando te refieres a _"la mejor forma"_ ¿Cuál es la forma actual en que lo estás haciendo que consideras que no es óptima?

Comment: En realidad no conozco como realizar el guardado de los datos en tabla maestra y detalle con JDBC. ¿Cómo es el proceso de guardado de datos en tabla maestra y detalle con JDBC con código autogenerados?

Comment: Tienes una etiqueta que dice spring. ¿Estás usando spring? ¿Spring boot? ¿Spring Data JDBC? ¿Qué cosa de spring estás usando? Porque por ejemplo Spring JDBC tiene un JDBCTemplate que te hace la vida súper sencilla.

Comment: estoy usando spring-jdbc-3.2.13, realice una inserción de datos a una tabla con PrepareStatement pero para guardar en una sola ejecución a una tabla maestra y detalle, ya no la tuve muy claro como hacerlo. Mas por el tema de que las tablas ya  generan el código automáticamente.

Comment: Deberías de enseñar los repositorios que usas pero a grosso modo **save** devuelve el objeto insertado, es decir de ahí puedes obtener el id generado para usarlo en la siguiente inserción del detalle. Y todo esto en una trasnacción.